# how to load an image in label when button pressed PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am new in programming in PyQt and when i run this code then pres button the window always get notresponding.

and second question how can i load image in label when button pressed, i spend 3hours to get a question but i didn't get answer :((
how to fix it and sorry before my english bad

```
import sys
import cv2
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage,QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog,QApplication,QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class ShowImage (QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ShowImage,self).__init__()
        loadUi('ganteng.ui',self)
        self.image=None
        self.loadButton.clicked.connect(self.loadClicked)

@pyqtSlot()
def loadClicked(self):
    self.loadImage('2.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

def loadImage(self,Flname):
    self.image=cv2.imread(flname)
    self.displayImage()

def displayImage(self):
    qformat=QImage.Format_Indexed8

    if len(self.image.shape)==3:
        if (self.image.shape[2])==4:
            qformat=QImage.Format_RGBA8888

        else:
            qformat=QImage.Format_RGB888

            img=QImage(self.image,self.image.shape[1],self.image.shape[0],self.image.strides[0],qformat)
            img=img.rgbSwapped()

            self.imgLabel.serPixmap (QPixmap.fromImage(img))
            self.imgLabel.setAlignment (qtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window=ShowImage()
window.setWindowTitle('gambar')
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

[this the ui window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btu6B.png)

Comment: **typos everywhere** : change `Flname` to `flname`, `serPixmap` to `setPixmap`, `qtCore` to `QtCore`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine with you, just a few typos. Be attentive :)

```
import sys
import cv2
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore    import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic       import loadUi

class ShowImage (QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        loadUi('ganteng.ui',self)
        self.image = None
        self.loadButton.clicked.connect(self.loadClicked)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def loadClicked(self):
        self.loadImage('head.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    def loadImage(self, flname, cv ):                  # Flname <-> flname;  + , cv
        self.image = cv2.imread(flname)
        self.displayImage()

    def displayImage(self):
        qformat = QImage.Format_Indexed8

        if len(self.image.shape) == 3:
            if (self.image.shape[2]) == 4:
                qformat = QImage.Format_RGBA8888
            else:
                qformat = QImage.Format_RGB888

                img = QImage(self.image,
                             self.image.shape[1],
                             self.image.shape[0],
                             self.image.strides[0],
                             qformat)
                img = img.rgbSwapped()

                self.imgLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(img))      # serPixmap <-> setPixmap
                self.imgLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter    # qtCore    <-> QtCore
                                         | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ShowImage()
    window.setWindowTitle('gambar')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Typos should not be answered because they will not be useful to anyone, you have the privilege to comment so it is best to indicate in a comment

Comment: If you really wanted to be helpful, you would explain how to run a pyqt script on windows so that it will show python tracebacks properly. That way, they can learn how to debug code themselves, rather than posting off-topic questions on SO.

Comment: hahaha thanks the code run normaly :)